# Conversion from Arraylist<Byte> to byte array in android

Tags: java, android

I have a arraylist of Bytes and i am converting them into a byte array.I have used the following method.However it gives me the following error:
 E/AndroidRuntime(5228): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.primitives.Bytes

```
ArrayList<Byte> byteArrayList_song=new ArrayList<Byte>();
byte[] bytes_song_byte;

 for(int i=0;i<int_arraylist.size();i++)
 {
            bytes_song_byte=Bytes.toArray(byteArrayList_song);                
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Guava is not on your class path, also you should remove the for loop from the above code, as that is what the Guava function does for you.

```
ArrayList<Byte> byteArrayList_song = new ArrayList<Byte>();
byte[] bytes_song_byte = Bytes.toArray(byteArrayList_song);
```

Comment: Thanks dicarlo2 But i have add the library as a external jar file into my project.Bulid Path->Configure Build Path->Add External Jars.Do i need to make any more changes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this conversion without external libs

```
    byte[] bytes_song_byte = new byte[byteArrayList_song.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArrayList_song.size(); i++) {
        bytes_song_byte[i] = byteArrayList_song.get(i);
    }
```

note that if byteArrayList_song has any `null` elements this code will throw a NullPointerException

Comment: Indeed you could but, the purpose of all of Guava's convenience functions like `Bytes.toArray` is exactly that, for convenience. No reason to type the above when it can be wrapped up in a function for you.

Comment: With that said, would I include an entire external library just to use a couple of `toArray` functions? Probably not, I'd just write them myself.

Comment: I tried the above code but when i try print the size of the bytes_song_byte it gives me null

Comment: You probably mean 0. Your ArrayList is probably empty, add some values: byteArrayList_song.add(true); byteArrayList_song.add(false);

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
      ArrayList<Byte> byteArrayList_song=new ArrayList<Byte>();
        byte[] bytes_song_byte;
        bytes_song_byte=byteArrayList_song.toArray(new Byte[byteArrayList_song.size()]);
```